# Convert datetime from xml to c# object using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following code below:

```
XDocument xmldocument = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
List<Client> clients = (from client in xmldocument.Element("Clients").Elements("Client")
                       select new Client
                       {
                             Name = client.Element("Name").Value,
                             Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(client.Element("Birthday").Value)
                       }).ToList();
```

And here is my xml:

```
 <Clients>
 <Client>
      <Name>Firstname Lastname</Name>
      <Birthday>01/01/1991</Birthday>
 </Client>
 </Clients>
```

My problem is I am getting a null reference error whenever I tried to run the code. But when I removed the Birthday from the linq statement, I am getting the data so I assumed that there must be something wrong on my converting to date.

Did I missed something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

use [`XElement` to `DateTime` conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343203.aspx) instead of `Convert.ToDateTime`:

```
XDocument xmldocument = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
List<Client> clients = (from client in xmldocument.Element("Clients").Elements("Client")
                       select new Client
                       {
                             Name = (string)client.Element("Name"),
                             Birthday = (DateTime)client.Element("Birthday")
                       }).ToList();
```

Comment: Error: Cannot convert string to DateTime

Comment: Are you sure you've delete the `.Value` call after `Element("Birthday")`?

Comment: What if my date is a json date? Can I also convert it to c# object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Parse method:

```
DateTime.Parse(client.Element("Birthday").Value).Date
```

or the ParseExact method with the format dd/MM/yyyy

```
DateTime.ParseExact(client.Element("Birthday").Value, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
```

or the ParseExact method with the format MM/dd/yyyy

```
DateTime.ParseExact(client.Element("Birthday").Value, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
```